# Enable monetization for specific videos on YouTube

Tags: youtube

I want to enable monetization for [my channel](http://youtube.com/BhargavGarreVenkata). The problem is that all but 1 of my videos have copyrighted music I can't make money from. How can I enable monetization for only that one video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to monetize a video on YouTube it must adhere to the [video monetization criteria](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/97527) which states:

> - Your content is advertiser-friendly.
> - You created the content or have permission to use it commercially.
> - **You are able to provide documentation proving you own commercial rights to all audio and video content.**
> - Your content complies with YouTube’s Terms of Service and Community Guidelines.
> - YouTube reserves the right to disable monetization for accounts that do not follow our guidelines.

[This means you cannot monetize third-party content that you have purchased unless its rights owner grants you commercial use rights.](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2490020) It is solely up to the copyright holder when reviewing the video to determine whether to allow you to monetize the video using their content.

If you believe you have properly obtained the usage rights to use the copyright holder's content with a commercial usage license, you may file a counter claim on the YouTube Copyright Center.

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I want to know _how_ to enable monetization to only a specific video.

Comment: In that case then, what is the current status of https://www.youtube.com/features under Monetization, is [Enable](http://i.imgur.com/IyYO1C1.png) an option?

If it is currently enabled, do you see the [Monetization tab](http://i.imgur.com/XGAsJSM.png) under the video manager?

Finally, do you see the [Monetize with ads toggle?](http://i.imgur.com/vHSGZdH.png)

If you don't see one of these things as shown as in the screenshots, head to https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1727191?hl=en to find out why.

Comment: Enable is an option because I haven't enabled it yet. I wanted to figure this out first because I don't want those videos to get removed.

Comment: Well then you'll need to Enable it account wide, then for any videos that may have copyrighted materials you can turn off monetization. There's still no guarantee that your account won't be suspended if you do have copyrighted materials if you turn off monetization. Publishers who claim content ID on your videos will still be able to monetize your video without your permission.

Comment: There are 7 videos with copyrighted music, but 3 were recognized by Content ID (those artists monetized those videos). The rest don't seem to be recognized yet. Could those get deleted if I enable monetization and disable it for some videos like you said?

Comment: If they have already been marked by Content ID, you don't have anything to worry about, the copyright holders have already been notified by Google's automated system that matches copyrighted audio. Since the videos haven't been taken down it wouldn't change anything because you're not in control of the monetization settings on those videos anyways.

Comment: That's good, but what about the 4 videos that have not been identified by content ID yet? Is there a chance those could get removed?

Comment: Also, it says videos with "visuals" like logos and software are not eligible. If I'm making a simple tutorial and the logo of the software or website shows up, would that be not eligible?